# Why did cluster mode of Apache IoTDB Version 0.13 crash and fail to restart?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I started Apache IoTDB Version 0.13 in cluster mode, but it crashed inexplicably today. Then I tried to restart it, but the restart never succeeded. I have been using this version before and it has been running for several months. Today it suddenly crashed and restarted with this error. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0.13 cluster version of Apache IoTDB currently is not maintained frequently. It is recommended to upgrade to version 1.0 or above before running cluster version of IoTDB.